Does this derivation of the sum formula for geometric series make sense?
I want to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty ar^k = \frac{a}{1-r}$ when $|r| < 1$. If I can prove the sequence of partial sums $S_n$ converges to said formula, then I will have proven the series does as well. To derive a formula for $S_n$ I considered the following:
$S_n = a + ar +ar^2 + \cdots + ar^{n-1}$,
$rS_n = ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + \cdots + ar^n$
$S_n - rS_n = a - ar^n \rightarrow S_n = \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$
I now want to show $\{S_n \}_{n=1}^\infty \rightarrow \frac{a}{1-r}$. By the algebraic limit theorem, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r} = \left(\frac{a}{1-r}\right) \lim_{n \to \infty} (1-r^n)$. Thus we must show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-r^n) \rightarrow 1$. Further simplification with the algebraic limit theorem reduces this to showing that $\lim_{n \to \infty} r^n \rightarrow 0$.
Here is where I am unsure of my approach. By inspection one can easily tell that this limit goes to zero, but in the pursuit of rigor I wanted to prove it directly. To start, I will ignore the trivial case when $r = 0$. We can prove inductively that $\{r^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is monotonically decreasing or increasing in either case that $r$ is positive or negative respectively. Observe that by this monotonicity of the sequence and the assumption that $|r| < 1$ we can say that $\{r^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded. Since the sequence is bounded, we can say it converges to some limit point $L$ by the Monotone Convergence Theorem.
My idea was that since we know this sequence converges, we could try to do some algebra to prove $L = 0$. Since $\{r^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges, we know that $\{r^{n+1}\}_{n=1}^\infty \rightarrow L$ since this is the same sequence simply shifted a term. Now:
$r^{n+1} = r^n \cdot r$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} r^{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} r^n \cdot r \rightarrow L = Lr$ ....................................................(1)
Such an expression is only true if $r = 1$ or $L = 0$, yet $r=1$ contradicts our assumption that $|r| < 1$ so thus $L=0$.
It then follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r} = \left(\frac{a}{1-r}\right) \lim_{n \to \infty} (1-r^n) = \frac{a}{1-r}$ by the algebraic limit theorem.
My question is, is it allowed to do this sort of manipulation in $(1)$ and the logic that precedes it? I've seen similar manipulations done before, but it was in different contexts.

This is mostly fine although there's a small gap earlier in your argument: if $r$ is negative the sequence $r^n$ is not monotonic (either monotonically increasing or decreasing) so you have to work a little harder in this case. But it suffices to apply the same argument to $|r^n| = |r|^n$.
In any case, there's no issue with your deduction that $r = Lr$ once you know that the limit exists. If you want to be really careful, it follows from another application of what you're calling the algebraic limit theorem. A nice generalization of this argument is to consider a sequence $a_n$ defined by recursively by iterating a continuous function $f$, meaning that
$$a_{n+1} = f(a_n).$$
Here $f(x) = rx$. Then if the limit $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists, taking this limit on both sides gives $L = f(L)$, so $L$ is necessarily a fixed point of $f$. In this nice special case $f(x) = rx$ where $|r| < 1$ the only fixed point is $0$ but in more general versions of this argument there are other fixed points so we get more interesting possible behavior.

I see. If $r$ is negative then this would introduce an alternating bit. If we are considering a geometric series of negative terms, is the proper placement of that negative sign to the $a$ constant instead, since it won’t oscillate as $n$ iterates higher and higher?

@Matt: $a$ does not help you, the terms oscillate regardless of the sign of $a$. We are considering, to be concrete, a geometric series like $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{8} \pm \dots $.
